# Get custom taxonomy terms with a true boolean value of ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an Advanced Custom Field called `frontpage`. Is true/false type.

I'm trying to recover all terms marked as true. I tried this:

```
$args = array(
      'hide_empty' => 0,
      'key' => 'frontpage',
      'compare' => '==',
      'value' => '1'
);

$terms = get_terms( 'people', $args );

if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->name;
    }
}
```

But this returns all terms, regardless true or false.

How can I get just true marked terms? Thanks!

**EDIT:** ACF docs says how to recover post, not how to recover terms:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/

**EDIT2:** The object returned does not contain custom fields, just standard meta data:

```
Array ( 
[0] => WP_Term Object ( 
  [term_id] => 2 
  [name] => Cristina Aiken Soux 
  [slug] => cristina-aiken-soux 
  [term_group] => 0 
  [term_taxonomy_id] => 2 
  [taxonomy] => personas 
  [description] => Cras in elementum enim, vitae volutpat sapien. Duis at sem in quam ultrices hendrerit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent. 
  [parent] => 0 
  [count] => 1 
  [filter] => raw )
)
```

So, the first question is, how can I recover the meta fields of each term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try this query to retrieve posts of a certain $term for a given $taxonomy that have $acf_field_name set to true:

```
 $args = array(
   'hide_empty' => 0,
     'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key' => $acf_field_name,
            'compare' => '==',
            'value' => '1'
         )
     ),
     'tax_query' => array(
          array(
             'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
             'field' => 'slug',
             'terms' => $taxonomy_terms,
          ),
     )
 );
 $query = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Finally I did another thing. I will post it in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've used another approach: To get all terms and, in the loop, ouput just terms marked in the custom field.

```
$args = array(
        'hide_empty' => 0
  );

  $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
  if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
      foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $custom_field = get_field('custom_field', $term);
        if( $custom_field == '1' ):
            echo $term->name;
        php endif; ?>
```